# Search bar missing in Outlook 2019

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2019

Today I started Outlook 2019 and wanted to search for an e-mail but I can't. The search bar which is normally above *All*, *Unread*, ... (which is again above the list of e-mails) is missing. To be clear, what's missing is the input field where the text "Search current mailbox" appears in this example screen shot:

[image: Look at the input field where the text "Search current mailbox" appears]

Where do I activate it again?

I made a quick Google search without success. I looked into the Outlook options, but didn't find an entry. Under the ribbon tab *View* you can only change between *Compact*, *Separate* and *Preview*.

Now I run the Microsoft Support and Recovery Assistant (SaRA) with the following result:

**Outlook Configuration Protocol**

> New email notifications are not displayed because the Outlook shortcut (Outlook 2016.lnk) is missing from the 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs' folder. Windows requires an Outlook shortcut to exist in this folder for email notifications to work. Click the 'Click here ...' link and then follow the steps at the bottom of the article for repairing your Office 'Click-to-run' installation.

**Outlook Verification Protocol**

```
14:24:35.117: Starting Collecting Data phase.
14:24:35.117: Scan type: Full Scan.
14:24:35.439: Die angegebene Domäne ist nicht vorhanden, oder es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden
14:24:35.441: Logged on User Details (status=CompletedOkay)
14:24:35.441: Collecting <PII:StringRemoved> System and OS Details
14:24:35.471: Drive Info (status=CompletedOkay)
14:24:35.472: Computer Details (status=CompletedOkay)
14:24:35.506: Pointing Devices (status=CompletedOkay)
14:24:35.520: Video Controllers (status=CompletedOkay)
14:24:35.642: Network Adapters (status=CompletedOkay)
14:24:35.653: Network Drive Details (status=CompletedOkay)
14:24:35.924: Printers (status=CompletedOkay)
14:24:40.788: DxDiag (status=CompletedOkay)
14:24:40.788: <PII:StringRemoved> System Details (status=CompletedOkay)
14:24:42.091: Services (Running) (status=CompletedOkay)
14:24:42.121: Operating System Details (status=CompletedOkay)
14:24:53.420: Der Remoteserver hat einen Fehler zurückgegeben: (404) Nicht gefunden.
14:24:53.420: Der Remoteserver hat einen Fehler zurückgegeben: (404) Nicht gefunden.
14:24:55.518: Der Remoteserver hat einen Fehler zurückgegeben: (404) Nicht gefunden.
14:24:55.518: Der Remoteserver hat einen Fehler zurückgegeben: (404) Nicht gefunden.
14:24:57.962: Der Remoteserver hat einen Fehler zurückgegeben: (404) Nicht gefunden.
14:24:57.962: Der Remoteserver hat einen Fehler zurückgegeben: (404) Nicht gefunden.
14:25:00.783: Der Remoteserver hat einen Fehler zurückgegeben: (404) Nicht gefunden.
14:25:00.783: Der Remoteserver hat einen Fehler zurückgegeben: (404) Nicht gefunden.
14:25:03.393: Der Remoteserver hat einen Fehler zurückgegeben: (404) Nicht gefunden.
14:25:03.393: Der Remoteserver hat einen Fehler zurückgegeben: (404) Nicht gefunden.
14:25:05.791: Collecting Installed Updates
14:25:05.805: Installed Office Updates (status=CompletedOkay)
14:25:05.843: Collecting Current profile ('Outlook') information
14:25:07.046: Collecting data about stores in profile
14:25:07.113: Scanning Folders in Store (<PII:StringRemoved>.some@email.com)
14:25:11.505: Folders in Store (<PII:StringRemoved>.some@email.com) (status=CompletedOkay)
14:25:11.552: Collecting Rules in Store (<PII:StringRemoved>.some@email.com)
14:25:11.552: Die angegebene Domäne ist nicht vorhanden, oder es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden
14:25:12.465: Rules in Store (<PII:StringRemoved>.some@email.com) (status=CompletedOkay)
14:25:12.509: Scanning Folders in Store (<PII:StringRemoved>.another@email.com)
14:25:21.947: Folders in Store (<PII:StringRemoved>.another@email.com) (status=CompletedOkay)
14:25:21.996: Collecting Rules in Store (<PII:StringRemoved>.another@email.com)
14:25:21.996: Die angegebene Domäne ist nicht vorhanden, oder es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden
14:25:22.438: Rules in Store (<PII:StringRemoved>.another@email.com) (status=CompletedOkay)
14:25:22.439: Stores in profile (status=CompletedOkay)
14:25:22.587: Profile registry (status=CompletedOkay)
14:25:22.588: Current profile ('Outlook') information (status=CompletedOkay)
14:25:22.606: Collecting Add-ins(Microsoft and third-party) and third-party modules
14:25:22.739: Ein 32-Bit-Prozess kann nicht auf Module eines 64-Bit-Prozesses zugreifen.
14:25:22.740: Microsoft and third-party module details (status=CompletedOkay)
14:25:23.007: Add-ins with known problems (status=CompletedOkay)
14:25:35.787: Microsoft Dynamics CRM (status=CompletedOkay)
14:25:35.787: Collecting Office Registry Settings
14:25:44.881: Office Registry Settings (status=CompletedOkay)
14:25:44.889: Office Policies (status=CompletedOkay)
14:25:44.889: Collecting Outlook Security Settings
14:25:44.891: Outlook Security Settings (status=CompletedOkay)
14:25:44.892: Collecting Application Event Log Entries for Last Outlook crashes
14:25:46.201: Application Event Log Entries for Last Outlook crashes (status=CompletedOkay)
14:25:46.520: Collecting Application Event Log Entries for Full OAB Downloads
14:25:46.694: Collecting Application Event Log Entries for Event 19
14:25:46.878: Collecting Application Event Log Entries for Event 25
14:25:47.442: Collecting Application Event Log Entries for Add-ins Load Time
14:25:48.351: Application Event Log Entries for Add-ins Load Time (status=CompletedOkay)
14:25:48.934: Collecting Microsoft Office Alerts
14:25:48.999: Microsoft Office Alerts - Outlook (status=CompletedOkay)
14:25:50.823: Collecting other miscellaneous data
14:25:52.966: Collecting Registry Values Introduced by Outlook Updates
14:25:52.979: Registry Values Introduced by Outlook Updates (status=CompletedOkay)
14:25:54.851: Authentication registry (status=CompletedOkay)
14:25:54.851: Windows Compatibility Settings (status=CompletedOkay)
14:25:54.852: Browser (status=CompletedOkay)
14:25:54.871: Microsoft Office Alerts - Common (status=CompletedOkay)
14:25:54.876: Installed .Net Runtimes (status=CompletedOkay)
14:25:54.931: Internet Cache folder attributes (status=CompletedOkay)
14:25:55.031: WebClient Service Status (status=CompletedOkay)
14:25:55.032: Miscellaneous (status=CompletedOkay)
14:25:55.041: Completed Collecting Data phase.
14:25:55.652: Starting Postprocessing Rules phase.
14:25:56.046: Completed Postprocessing Rules phase.
```

Comment: Have you tried just running a repair on your office?

Comment: No, do you think it would help?

Comment: yes - that or you could try resetting your views first; the repair options are usually decent at fixing wonky things like this.

Comment: now I made a quick repair and it still isn't there

Comment: did you try the full/online repair?

Comment: You can install available updates for both Office and Windows to see if it helps.

Comment: @mael': Now I made the online repair without success.

Comment: @Perry: I have now installed the latest updates without success. I think it must be a configuration issue?

Comment: do you have the correct office version? i.e. if you're on 64-bit Windows, using 64-bit Office?

Comment: @mael': Yes, everything is 64 bit. It has worked before - so something has changed (update?).

Comment: Haven't seen similar reports of this issue. You can try Microsoft Support and Recovery Assistant (SaRA) to run tests. It can gather the Outlook profile configuration information that's helpful when you troubleshoot problems: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4098558/how-to-scan-outlook-by-using-the-sara-tool

Comment: @Perry: Thanks for the tip. I edited my question with the results. The issue still exists and I can't find something useful from the logs ... Is re-installing my last option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Office 2019. Don't know if this has been fixed. Because all other options didn't solved the issue, I did the last thing I could do:

I re-installed Office. Now the search bar is here again and the error never appeared again up to today.

Answer (score -1):

In Outlook 2019, the search field is in the title bar on the very top.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot? Mine doesn‘t seem to have it. Or do you mean Office 365?